# Positioning an element outside the containing element

Tags: javascript, css, css-position, userscripts

I have a webpage with code I cannot change which is set up something like this:

```
<table style="width: 750px; margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto">
  <tr>
    <td>
      <table>
        <tr><td><div id=1></td></tr>
        <tr><td><div id=2></td></tr>
        <tr><td><div id=3></td></tr>
        <tr><td><div id=4></td></tr>
      </table>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

I'd like to add an element (via userscript) to the right of the outer table which lines up with `div` 1, 2, 3, or 4. Is there a way to do this? Maybe measure the current position of the elements then absolutely position relative to the outer table?

(The actual HTML is far more messy; there are many more siblings and parents, but this is the heart of the code.)

Comment: The code above does not really equate to valid html. I'm pretty sure I get what your questions is though. It would be nice to have a bit more information for the code structure. Would you be able to provide the code for the web page or the table?

Comment: It's pretty hairy HTML. I've pasted it at https://pastebin.com/NsMPtvbv ; `id="edit_Comment"` corresponds to one of the `id`s above.

Comment: have you found a different solution?

Answer (score 0):

### Position an element adjacent to table rows

Create and append the desired element to your table. Then create and add custom styles that reflect the position of the table row. I've written down some comments below to help navigate the code.

```js
// Setup additional element
const yourContent = document.createElement("div");
yourContent.setAttribute("class", "content");
const yourText = document.createTextNode("Lorem ipsum");
yourContent.appendChild(yourText);

// Find the element you would like to attach to
const graphElem = document.getElementsByClassName("rows");

// Set the styles to be added 
const cssTemplateString = `td > .rows > .content{
    position: absolute;
    left: ${graphElem[0].clientWidth}px; // For element to appear on the left side set to "-" ( negative value )
    height: calc(${graphElem[0].clientHeight}px +2px);  // The 2 extra pixels are for the border
    width: calc(${graphElem[0].clientWidth}px + 2px);
    background: white;
    padding: 3rem;
    border: 1px solid gray;
    top: 0;
}`;
const styleTag = document.createElement("style");
styleTag.innerHTML = cssTemplateString;

// Add styles to the head tag
document.head.insertAdjacentElement("beforeend", styleTag);

// Only required for this example
for (let i = 0; i < graphElem.length; i++) {
  graphElem[i].addEventListener("click", function (event) {
    event.target.appendChild(yourContent);
  });
}
```

```css
td > .rows {
  border: 1px solid gray;
  width: 8rem;
  padding: 3rem;
  background: whitesmoke;
}

td {
  position: relative; /* The additional content will be positioned relative to this */
}
```

### Demo : https://jsfiddle.net/hexzero/82bpaL4e/

If you click on the table row in the demo, the content will appear on the right.